# How can I create sentence permutations from this word matrix?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix

I want to generate sentences by selecting exactly one word from each row, and appending these words such that the word from row 0 will always be first, the word from row 1 will always be second, and so on.

E.G. "Here is a monkey", "here si a monkey", "her are the monk-ey"

It will be great if someone can also point me to the relevant general maths/algorithm (Combinatorics - I sense this is a combination problem). More importantly, I need to do this in Python.

```
sent_matrix = [ ['Here', 'here', 'her', 'ere'],
                ['is', 'si', 'are', 'was'],
                ['a', 'the', 'an', 'there'],
                ['monkey', 'monk-ey', 'mon-key', 'monkee']
              ]
```

Comment: Do you always have n sentences, each with n words?

Comment: No, it can be (m x n). n is always constant (10 words per row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `itertools.product` as follows:

```
import itertools

sent_matrix = [['Here', 'here', 'her', 'ere'],
               ['is', 'si', 'are', 'was'],
               ['a', 'the', 'an', 'there'],
               ['monkey', 'monk-ey', 'mon-key', 'monkee']
              ]

answer = [' '.join(perm) for perm in itertools.product(*sent_matrix)]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
['Here is a monkey',
 'Here is a monk-ey',
 'Here is a mon-key',
 'Here is a monkee',
 ...
 'ere was there monkey',
 'ere was there monk-ey',
 'ere was there mon-key',
 'ere was there monkee']
```

Comment: Thanks. For 10 words a row, this is taking a lot of memory and time. Is there an efficient way?

Comment: Wait. It is important to note that I do not want a disturbance in word-order : All words should retain their indics in the sentence. E.G. 'here' or its variants will always appear first.

Comment: e.g. 'monkey is a here' is not a valid sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choice`

Try:

```
import random

sent_matrix = [ ['Here', 'here', 'her', 'ere'],
                ['is', 'si', 'are', 'was'],
                ['a', 'the', 'an', 'there'],
                ['monkey', 'monk-ey', 'mon-key', 'monkee']
              ]

result = ""
for elem in sent_matrix:
    result += random.choice(elem) + " "

print result
```

Comment: This generates one combination successfully, but I'm pretty sure the OP is after all of the combinations

Comment: Yeah, I need all combinations. But good to have this answer for completeness :-)

Comment: Good stuff - it is often useful to see various ways of approaching a problem!

Answer (score 0):

How about using itertools.permutations?

```
import itertools

n = 4
sent_list = []
for perm in itertools.permutations(range(n)):
    random_sent = [sent_matrix[i][j] for (i,j) in enumerate(perm)]
    sent_list.append(random_sent)
```

This could be slow and memory expensive for large n.
If you simply want to process these random sentences line-by-line, you should consider using yield instead of creating a list.

Comment: Sorry, this solution will work only for n x n lists of lists.
But it shouldn't be hard to fix.